# How can I make a flat wooden material?

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm making this kitchen scene and I am trying to get the cupboard material to look like the one in the picture. Currently I think this looks to "plastic" and I want it to look more real. Is there any hope or should I change to a whole other material?

The black one is what I have tried.

[image: What I want it to look like vs What I can achieve]

Comment: Probably showing the material setting for the black parts could help to help you, don't you think?

Comment: I'd say that improving the lighting would be more important. At the moment it's hard to see any details in the material because there are zero highlights.